# How to Add Custom Logo Instead of Menu home Icon in WordPress Website?

Tags: wordpress, menu

We want to use custom logo insted of menu home icon. Here is our website https://www.anonymoushackers.net/ Here is the screenshot for reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhqos.png) We want to place the small logo instead of icon that we have highlighted in the screenshot.

Here is the logo image that we want to use instead of icon. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXmZQ.jpg)

We also want to know that which class or id is suitable for this. We tried and wont be able to find that particular id or class.Please suggest if anyone knows

Answer (score 0):

It's fontawesome icon. You can edit theme template and replace `<i class="fa fa-home"></i>` with `<img src="logo.png" alt=""/>`

Or override css style

```
.mnp-home-icon .fa-home:before {
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(https://www.anonymoushackers.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/GGGGGGGG.jpg);
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change the custom Logo you have to change the logo section in header.php

```
<?php if (function_exists('the_custom_logo')) {the_custom_logo(); }?>
```

Comment: Anyone knows how to find that part of the template.